# Still getting Maxeventlisteners exceeded node error after adding concurrency to aync function

Tags: node.js

When running the following function without concurrency I would get the node error:

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
>   detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to
>   increase limit

```
async function addSentimentToTweets(tweets) {
  try {
    return Promise.all(
      tweets.map(async tweet => {
        const sentiment = await getTextSentiment(tweet.text);
        return { ...tweet, sentiment };
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

As a result I used the npm packages promise-limit and bluebird to add concurrency. The code with promise-limit for example was:

```
const limit = promiseLimit(5);

async function addSentimentToTweets(tweets) {
  try {
    return await Promise.all(
      tweets.map(tweet => {
        return limit(async () => {
          const sentiment = await getTextSentiment(tweet.text);
          return { ...tweet, sentiment };
        });
      })
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

But I still get the error. The only way I can get rid of it is using something like:

```
require("events").EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 110;
```

To mask the problem.

But does anyone know how to actually solve it? I guess all the listeners are added when using Promise.all even when they aren't all executed concurrently. Is there a solution to map through async functions but only add and resolve X promises at one time? Or am i barking up the wrong tree entirely and there is a fundamental error in the above code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `process.on('warning', (warning) => console.warn(warning.stack));` add this line to the top of your application, maybe it will help you find what happen is going on.

Comment: good article about this issue, you should read it, https://medium.com/@jongleberry/understanding-node-jss-possible-eventemitter-leak-error-message-bc2ee68b24ea I think you have something in  `getTextSentiment()` that adds a listener on event and never remove it, and in most cases you should define one event listener for all you object, thats my guess without looking at `getTextSentiment()`

Comment: if you run your app like this `node --trace-warnings yourapp.js`, it wil tell where are problem is coming from